# How can my server be both "unreachable" and "online"?

Tags: chrony

I'm trying to set up a chrony server/client pair. My chrony version is 2.4.

When I check the sources on the client side, I see that the server is unreachable

```
chronyc sources -v
210 Number of sources = 1

  .-- Source mode  '^' = server, '=' = peer, '#' = local clock.
 / .- Source state '*' = current synced, '+' = combined , '-' = not combined,
| /   '?' = unreachable, 'x' = time may be in error, '~' = time too variable.
||                                                 .- xxxx [ yyyy ] +/- zzzz
||      Reachability register (octal) -.           |  xxxx = adjusted offset,
||      Log2(Polling interval) --.      |          |  yyyy = measured offset,
||                                \     |          |  zzzz = estimated error.
||                                 |    |           \
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
^? 192.168.2.101                 0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
```

However, looking at the NTP activity, tells me that it's online.

```
chronyc activity
200 OK
1 sources online
0 sources offline
0 sources doing burst (return to online)
0 sources doing burst (return to offline)
0 sources with unknown address
```

The [chronyc documentation](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/doc/2.4/chronyc.html) says the following

> The report shows the number of servers and peers in 5 states:
>
> online
>
> the server or peer is currently online (i.e. assumed by chronyd to be reachable)
>
> offline
>
> the server or peer is currently offline (i.e. assumed by chronyd to be unreachable, and no measurements from it will be attempted.)

This makes me think that "unreachable" and "online" are incompatible states. What would likely lead to this situation?

Comment: Oh DenverCoder, somebody answer you please. Also the official documentation is down...